# How to show database from two different tables in one page on Laravel 10?

Tags: php, laravel, database, erp, laravel-10

So, I had supplier and Materials table that i want to show the data on the same pages? I want to make ERP for store material data

Supplier Models :

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\GudangMaterial;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class Supplier extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table='supplier';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'nama',
        'alamat',
        'email',
        'noTelp',
        'update_at',
        'create_at',
    ];

    public function gudangproduk()
     {
        return $this->belongsToMany(GMaterial::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Material Models :

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class GMaterial extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'gmaterial';

    protected $fillable = [

        'name',
        'kode',
        'jmlh',
        'jmlh_min',
        'satuan',
        
        ];

        public function supply() {

            return $this->belongsToMany(Supplier::class, 'group_material');
        }
}
```

The Controller :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\GMaterial;
use App\Models\Supplier;

 public function material() {

        $bahan = gmaterial::all();

        return view('master.material')->with('bahan', $bahan);
    }

public function simpanMaterial(Request $request) {

        $bahan = new gmaterial;
        $bahan->nama = $request->input('namaProduk');
        $bahan->harga = $request->input('harga');
        $bahan->stock = $request->input('stock');
        $bahan->tanggal = $request->input('tanggal');
        $bahan->save();

        return redirect()->route('material')->with('success', 'Data berhasil disimpan!');
    }

    public function updateMaterial(Request $request,$id) {

        $bahan['namaProduk'] = $request->nama;
        $bahan['harga'] = $request->harga;
        $bahan['stock' ]= $request->stock;
        $bahan['tanggal'] = $request->tanggal;

        gmaterial::whereId($id)->update($bahan);

        return redirect()->route('material')->with('success', 'Data telah Di Update!');

    }

    public function hapusMaterial(Request $request,$id) {

        $bahan = gmaterial::find($id);

        if($bahan){
            $bahan->delete();
        }

        return redirect()->route('material')->with('success', 'Data telah terhapus!');
    }
}
```

Im try to using hasMany and dump the data but still show null.

What i expecting is the data will show in the same page and i can add more data, delete data and Edit the data

Kode Material   Name Material   Supplier    QTY QTY Min  Satuan  Action
1               Wooden           Test           20      5        Pcs     Delete Edit